# Create property with no implemented setter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.name = None  # type: str

    def introduce(self):
        print("I'm " + self.name)


class Alice(Human):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.name = "Alice"


class Bob(Human):
    def __init__(self, rude: bool) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.rude = rude

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return "BOB!" if self.rude else "Bob"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    alice = Alice()
    alice.introduce()
    bob = Bob(rude=True)
    bob.introduce()
```

In the code above, there is an abstract `Human` class (in reality it is not a human and has more complex methods, not related to the problem). Most of its implementations would set their names by simply assigning a string to the `name` attribute (just as `Alice`). But there are few exceptions, like `Bob`, when there is more complex logic assigned (the value depends on the object state in the moment of resolving).

Therefore in `Bob` class I created a custom getter for the `name` property. But as an effect, it is impossible to create a class instance, because invoking the superconstructor results in the following error.

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

And it is impossible to add a naive setter as well.

```
@name.setter
def name(self, name: str):
    self.name = name
```

Why? Because it would result in an infinite loop. How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not make a dummy setter

```
@name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        pass
```

When `self.name = None` is executed it will call this setter and actually do nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that your subclasses will assign `name`, then you can leave out the assignment in the parent constructor. Right now, `Human` is attempting to set to `name`, when there is no setter. If you removed it from the `Human` constructor, then `Human` can look like this:

```
class Human:
    def introduce(self):
        print("I'm " + self.name)
```

Comment: True, but in a current state it helps with development (by offering type hints and attribute hints in the IDE).

Answer (score 1):

For class `Bob`I would have used something like this in this case:

```
@name.setter
def name(self, name: str):
    self._name = name
```

Afterwards you can do whatever you want in the more complex getter with the internal value. Or did I get the question wrong?

Executing the code would give:

`I'm Alice`
`I'm BOB!`

Comment: Nice, though the internal attribute is unnecessary here, as it would never be used. Still, it looks like the solution.